# TimestampedGeoJson shows every point inserted in a map, rather than removing the previous one inserted

Tags: python, gps, geojson, folium

Good morning everyone, i'm trying to show an animated bicycle in a map.
I'm using python with TimestampedGeoJson for the dynamic movement of the bike.
As i'm not a python expert i'm struggling with the result i want to achieve.
I got good progress, but i have a problem; for every line dynamically draw i get also a point, so the map become messy very fast.
Is there a way to drow only one Point at time, then delete the previous?

Here's a picture for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjrSw.png

My code is as follow:

```
import folium, webbrowser
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson
import json

with open('json.txt') as json_file:
    json_data = json_file.read()

lines = json.loads(json_data)

map = folium.Map(location = [45.541603088378906, 9.188777923583984], zoom_start = 12)

features = [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": line["coordinates"],
        },
        "properties": {
            "times": line["dates"],
            "style": {
                "color": line["color"],
                "weight": line["weight"] if "weight" in line else 5,
            }
        }
    }
    for line in lines
]

TimestampedGeoJson(
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": features,
    },
    period="PT4M",
    add_last_point=True,
).add_to(map)

map.save('map.html')

webbrowser.open('C:/Users/samue/OneDrive/Desktop/Sport-sessions/map.html', new=2)
```

My data, contained in a .txt file, is built like this:

```
[
    {
        "color": "red",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                9.188777923583985,
                45.541603088378909
            ],
            [
                9.188661575317383,
                45.54198455810547
            ]
        ],
        "dates": [
            "2023-08-20 06:52:30+00:00",
            "2023-08-20 06:52:43+00:00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "red",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                9.188661575317383,
                45.54198455810547
            ],
            [
                9.188529014587403,
                45.54233169555664
            ]
        ],
        "dates": [
            "2023-08-20 06:52:43+00:00",
            "2023-08-20 06:52:53+00:00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "red",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                9.188529014587403,
                45.54233169555664
            ],
            [
                9.188283920288086,
                45.54268264770508
            ]
        ],
        "dates": [
            "2023-08-20 06:52:53+00:00",
            "2023-08-20 06:53:03+00:00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "red",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                9.188283920288086,
                45.54268264770508
            ],
            [
                9.188128471374512,
                45.543067932128909
            ]
        ],
        "dates": [
            "2023-08-20 06:53:03+00:00",
            "2023-08-20 06:53:10+00:00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "red",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                9.188128471374512,
                45.543067932128909
            ],
            [
                9.187952041625977,
                45.543453216552737
            ]
        ],
        "dates": [
            "2023-08-20 06:53:10+00:00",
            "2023-08-20 06:53:17+00:00"
        ]
    }
]
```

Thank you for everybody who will help me out!